# Looking up arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array in JS and need to look up the data by doing checks against it, but am wondering how i do it =/

My array is structured like this :

```
//global array spritea
var listObj = {
    id: uid,
    data: [
        abposx,
        abposy,
        (abposx+imgwidth),
        (abposy-imgheight)
    ]
};                  

spritea.push(listObj);
```

This is in a loop so an example of the array is :

```
spritea = [
    {
        id: "135", 
        data: [9,129,345, 687]
    },
    {
        id: "239", 
        data: [596,382,0,687,33467]
    }
];
```

So what im trying to do is this:

Find

```
id where x is > data[0] && y > data[1] && x < data[2] && y < data[3]
```

And then it returns the id ?

Any one know how to do that? Its really confusing me =/

Comment: Which part is confusing you? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: What have you tried?  The easiest solution would be to just make a function that iterates over the array and checks each entry.

Comment: What are x and y? Are they abposx and abposy?

Comment: Well is my only option to loop all the data ? And if so how would such a loop be approached.. i'm aiming to try the most efficient way as possible as i need to be as least intensive as possible =/

x and y is mouse position in a canvas. They are all integer values.

Comment: You'll have to do some indexing then.  Given the data structure you posted, a loop is the only possible way.

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle example of such a function you mentioned?

Comment: *id where x is > data[0] && y > data[1] && x < data[2] && y < data[3]* You've already written most of the function...  Just do a loop over the array and do the comparison you stated there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be inefficient for large arrays since it's O(n) (simple linear search), but should do the trick:

```
spritea = [
    {
        id: "135", 
        data: [9,129,345, 687]
    },
    {
        id: "239", 
        data: [596,382,0,687,33467]
    }
];

function searchSprites(sprites, x, y) {
    var matches = [],
        i = 0,
        data = null;
    for (i = 0; i < sprites.length; ++i) {
        data = sprites[i].data;
        if (x > data[0] && y > data[1] && x < data[2] && y < data[3]) {
            matches.push(sprites[i].id);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
​
```

It's untested, but should work.  Also, if you need better performance, you're going to have to index the data somehow.

Edit: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mP6cH/3/

Comment: Can you explain indexing...? What does it do that allows better performance?

Comment: Indexing would entail either maintaining a separate structure or altering the way your data is stored so that queries on certain conditions can be completed in a more efficient manner.  As for the most effective way to index this data, that would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I see i will look into indexing more when i get to the efficient improvement stage of my engine :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to print the array so i can do checks cos it's not working at this end =/

Comment: Use something like Chrome's Developer Tools, or the Firebug extension for Firefox (I suggest Chrome's Dev Tools over Firebug).  Then you can do console.log(someVariable); and it will be output on the console.  To open the dev tools and see the console in Chrome, hit control + shift + j and then click on the console tab.

Comment: I did console.log(spritea); but i get like 100 + objects in the list, even though there is only meant to be 2 in my current test situation... =/ or do i have to console.log a specific part of the array only?

Comment: Hmmm that sounds like the object actually has 100 objects in it.  Are the objects meaningful, or what exactly are they?

Comment: They are objects on a map which the user clicks to interact. It only shows 2 but it repeats the 2 for like 50 + times. Its placed in a mouse down - im wondering if on mouse down executes it more than one whilst the mouse is pressed down =/ which is a pain

Comment: Well it definitely has 100 objects in it then, so something must be putting them there.

Comment: spritea.length = 48

Hmm thats odd. This is how im creating my array: http://www.paste.to/MzYxMDQ4  spritea is globally set i should mention. Can you see any thing wrong?

Comment: It's probably the event getting triggered over and over again.  You should add a console.log("test") right before the push() and see what seems to make it get called.

Comment: I have solved it now :) Because its created in an animation request i have to set array length to 0 each time the function is called to re-build the array.